# Webform module issue - content type not displaying

Tags: 7, webforms

By accident I deleted the Webform content type in my Drupal 7 installation. It was a complete accident and thought that I was deleting a different content type. I tried going through a couple of tutorials that I saw online but was unable to get the content type back. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

I stumbled across this: http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/feature/webforms/recreate which was a small step forward, but it still doesnt work. Has this happened to anyone before? I have tried uninstalling the and re-installing the module, clearing my cashe, and running cron. Still nothing.

Can anyone provide any suggestions? I can't be the only one that this has happened to before and there has to be so sort of fix to this... Also, please note that I am a relatively new Drupal developer.

Comment: Drupal 7? Can't you simply create a new content type called "Webform" with the machine name "webform" and enable it to be used as webform? That should get you back all the previously created webform content.

Comment: Just saw, that this is basically what they say in the link you posted. Can you explain what exactly is not yet working as expected?

Comment: So it seems that the user interface that comes with the webform module does not come back into play. So I cant designate who gets an email when the form is submitted and all of that stuff. Instead what happens, is that what would normally be on the UI is just displayed on my page and I would have to submit the stuff that way. But I dont have any of that other behind the scenes access from before...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: In addition to the missing details already mentionned on comment, the title of the question is too broad.

Comment: I actually just fixed it... It was kinda dumb but if it works i wont complain. I had to remove the file clear my cashe. Install the file again. Clear my cashe... deselect it in my modules. clear the cashe. Then went to modules>uninstall... then re-selected it again. I appreciate your interest in helping me though.

Comment: @PierreBuyle - sorry for it being too broad... I wasnt too sure how to exactly explain the issue. I hope that is more precise for your taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal can act funny when you start deleting things and then trying to reinstall them. Do you have access to your database?

If so uninstall webform and delete it - then head into your database and delete any webform tables that might still be hanging around.

Dont even try this without backing up your database first though incase you happen to delete anything important.

Then re-install webform.

This is a pretty drastic step and you will lose all data surrounding your webforms.

I have had to do this with other modules that have left tables behind when uninstalled and then they mess when reinstalling said modules.

Once again though if you take this route be careful what you delete.

Comment: You could also add just the missing database elements back by looking at the schema of the Webform install.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking, this exact same thing happened to me. It's easy to forget, but if you update a module to the latest version you need to update the DB. This is best achieved using Drush. For me, it was simply a case of running:

```
drush updb
```

All my webforms reappeared and started working correctly.